# Batch saving ef 6 records in a for loop

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6.1

Does any one know or explain why the following code throws the following errors mention below while using EF6? I am getting these errors intermittently. Also, please suggest on how to save records when an error occurs.

```
using (var context = GetNewDBEntities())
{
   for (var i = 0; i < Docs.Count; i++)
   {
      context.Docs.Add(Docs[i]);

      //Save 50 Records per batch
      if (i % 50 == 0)
          context.SaveChanges();
   }
  context.SaveChanges();
}
```

EF 6 drops connection for the above code with the following errors.

> 1. An error occurred while updating the entries.
> 2. The request failed to run because the batch is aborted, this can be caused by abort signal sent    from client, or another request is running in the same session, which makes the session busy. A severe error occurred on the current command. The results, if any, should be discarded.
> 3. Failed to establish a MARS session in preparation to send the request to the server. (provider: SMux Provider, error: 19 - Physical connection is not usable)

Comment: The batch works perfectly. Intermittently it throws the above mentioned errors and does not write to the database. Question is more specific to the errors as to what causes those errors.

Comment: OK, it seems that you should not have "multiple active result sets=true" in the connection string. I would not try to continue when this error occurs. The context may be in an inconsistent state. Could you show some details of a `Doc` object?

Comment: It's just a table rendered as a class object by EF, so when it cannot create a new session, does it rollback all the sessions? What exactly do you mean continue when this error occurs? and why not? it occurs intermittently.

Comment: Look at error 3: `error: 19 - Physical connection is not usable`. Seems like the database isn't local to the dev machine. I would first make a local copy of the database and try to do it there, it looks to me like there's an issue with the network connection.

Comment: Sorry, Should have mentioned that this error is from production, and the database doesn't exist on the same machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I included SqlAzureExecutionStrategy into EF6.1 and the errors dissapeared, atleast for 2 weeks without errors now.